# MYSQL query working fine in AWS RDS instances with 1 vCPU but hangs if running in instances with 2 vCPU or more

Tags: query-performance, mysql-5.7, amazon-rds, aws

I have this following SQL query below executed in a Lambda function. The Lambda function connected to AWS RDS running MySQL 5.7.22.

When this query is executed against an instance type db.t2.small or db.t2.micro, the query works fine and results are returned in a few seconds. These instance type have 1 vCPU

However, when we raise the instance type to db.t3.small or db.t3.medium, which has 2 vCPU, the query hangs until the lambda timeout (about 10 minutes). Even after the lambda function timeout, the DB CPU remains at 50% consumption for the longest time until I decided to reboot the RDS.

This is counter intuitive as I would think that having more vCPU should improve performance. I'm guessing it might be linked to multi threading somehow but unable to find any info. Hope to get some help/hints here.

Here's the SQL query in question

```
INSERT INTO
   CP58 (
   SELECT
      s.BRN, IFNULL(IFNULL((
      SELECT
         rtmp.DLR_CODE 
      FROM
         STABLE stmp, CP58_REPORT rtmp 
      WHERE
         stmp.DLR_CODE = rtmp.DLR_CODE 
         AND s.BRN = rtmp.BRN 
         AND stmp.HQ_FLAG = 'HQ' 
         AND stmp.STATUS = 'Active' 
      GROUP BY
         stmp.COMP_REGNO, rtmp.DLR_CODE 
      ORDER BY
         stmp.COMP_REGNO, SUM(rtmp.TOTAL) DESC LIMIT 1), 
         (
            SELECT
               rtmp.DLR_CODE 
            FROM
               STABLE stmp,
               CP58_REPORT rtmp 
            WHERE
               stmp.DLR_CODE = rtmp.DLR_CODE 
               AND s.BRN = rtmp.BRN 
               AND stmp.HQ_FLAG = 'HQ' 
            GROUP BY
               stmp.COMP_REGNO,
               rtmp.DLR_CODE 
            ORDER BY
               stmp.COMP_REGNO,
               SUM(rtmp.TOTAL) DESC LIMIT 1
         )
), 'NOHQDEALERCODE') as 'HQDEALERCODE', s.DEALERNAME, s.ADDRESS, IFNULL(MAX(x.CPTABLE_YEAR), MAX(y.EDTABLE_YEAR)) as 'YEAR', IFNULL(SUM(x.CPTABLE), 0) as 'CPTABLE_TOTAL', IFNULL(SUM(y.EDTABLE), 0) as 'EDTABLE_TOTAL', 
         (
            IFNULL(SUM(x.CPTABLE), 0) + IFNULL(SUM(y.EDTABLE), 0)
         )
         as 'TOTAL', '0' as 'PDF' 
      FROM
         (
            SELECT
               stmp.COMP_REGNO as 'BRN',
               stmp.DLR_CODE as 'DLR_CODE',
               stmp.DLR_NAME as 'DEALERNAME',
               CONCAT(stmp.ADDRESS, ' ', stmp.TOWN, ' ', stmp.POSTCODE, ' ', stmp.STATE) as 'ADDRESS' 
            from
               STABLE stmp 
            GROUP BY
               DLR_CODE
         )
         s 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
            (
               SELECT
                  subqc.DESTDEALERCODE as 'DEALERCODE',
                  SUM(subqc.RM) as 'CPTABLE',
                  YEAR(subqc.DATETIME) as 'CPTABLE_YEAR' 
               FROM
                  CPTABLE subqc 
               GROUP BY
                  subqc.DESTDEALERCODE
            )
            x 
            on x.DEALERCODE = s.DLR_CODE 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
            (
               SELECT
                  subsubqe.DEALERCODE as 'DEALERCODE',
                  SUM(subsubqe.AMOUNT) as 'EDTABLE',
                  YEAR(subsubqe.BANKACK_DATE) as 'EDTABLE_YEAR' 
               FROM
                  EDTABLE subsubqe 
               GROUP BY
                  subsubqe.DEALERCODE
            )
            y 
            on s.DLR_CODE = y.DEALERCODE 
      GROUP BY
         BRN 
      HAVING
         TOTAL > 0 
         AND HQDEALERCODE <> 'NOHQDEALERCODE')
```

When the query hangs, I ran the EXPLAIN command and below is the result. It remains in this state unchanged, while consuming 50% cpu, until I restart the DB server.

[image: Explain Query result]

Comment: It is probably linked to different execution plans on both systems.

Comment: Yes i suspect so...maybe the Query Optimizer is sending the query to multiple cores which caused locking?